# Trying to get property of non-object in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 156) Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, api

I have a Shell Script that execute a route API in my Laravel Application. However, when it execute it, I have a error from Token.

> Trying to get property of non-object
>         in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 156)

The route is to http://localhost:8000/api/soap. 
In SoapController, I redirect to other route inside to the application:

```
return redirect('/control_fich/'.$id_user.'/'.$date_utc);
```

The route is:

```
Route::get('control_fich/{id}/{date}','ControlFichController@index');
```

And I put this route how a except in the middleware VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
     namespace App\Http\Middleware;

     use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

 class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
 {
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'dropdown',
    'control_fich/*',
];
 }
```

But the error continues. What I have to do to execute an internal Controller from an API Controller?

Thanks

Comment: Which middleware do you use for your route? web?

Comment: This is the Middleware: Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { });

Comment: get routes don't  require csrf tokens anyway

Comment: Can you show your VerifyCsrfToken class code?

Comment: Ok. I edited my post.

Comment: As, you said, you have an error on line 156. Now where is the error, whats about your  error logs?

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

you should change your code in `VerifyCsrfToken class` into it:

```
protected $except = [
   'dropdown',
   'control_fich/*',
];
```

Comment: namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
     'dropdown',
     'control_fich/*',
 ];
}